# How do I configure the User Secrets in Asp.Net Core 2.0.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

How do I configure the User Secrets in Asp.Net Core 2.0.1?

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to [review the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=windows) because what you are asking is a bit broad.

Comment: if you really want to do it within the code, you can do it from the program.cs file. the start up file is called at a later stage

Comment: yep, as mentioned by @Nkosi there is a direct documentation for user secrets. if you are stuck somewhere you need to mention that in your question. there is no point of posting the default generated code with a broad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the context menu?

[image]

the `secrets.json` may look like this:

```
{
    "SqlConnectionString": "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Sample;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
}
```

Then use it in your code like this (assuming you are building a API controller)

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class YourController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public ApprovalController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<string>> GetAll()
    {
        using (var db = new SqlConnection(_configuration["SqlConnectionString"]))
        {
            // your code
        }
    }
```

Comment: the code example is a unnecessary and not recommended. The recommended way is to use the configuration in the startup (which is already done in the OPs code).

Comment: to add to this, you can also right click on the project and edit the .projcs file. here you can change the folder location of your secret.json file. this helps to share secrets across web apps within the same system